# Codeigniter, How to display select query result in json format?

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I have two tables
table1: **dr_country**

[image]

table2: **dr_city**

[image]

I have to fetch data from both tables. My required output should look like in format:

```
[{"id":"1","country_name":"Australia","country_code":"61","iso_code":"AUS","city":
[{"id":"1","city_name":"sydney"},{"id":"2","city_name":"melbourne"},{"id":"3","city_name":"perth"},{"id":"4","city_name":"brisbane"}]},
{"id":"2","country_name":"Bangladesh","country_code":"880","iso_code":"BGD","city":
[{"id":"5","city_name":"dhaka"},{"id":"6","city_name":"chittagong"}]}]
```

I model method looks like:

```
public function countryAction()
{
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('dr_country');
    $this->db->join('dr_city', 'dr_country.id = dr_city.country_id','left');

    $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
   if($result)
   {
        print_r(json_encode($result));

    }
    else
    {
         $detail = array(
            'status'=>'unsucess',   
           );

          echo  json_encode($detail); 
    }
}
```

It produce the output like:

```
[{"id":"1","country_name":"Australia","country_code":"61","iso_code":"AUS","city_name":"sydney","country_id":"1"},{"id":"2","country_name":"Australia","country_code":"61","iso_code":"AUS","city_name":"melbourne","country_id":"1"},{"id":"3","country_name":"Australia","country_code":"61","iso_code":"AUS","city_name":"perth","country_id":"1"},{"id":"4","country_name":"Australia","country_code":"61","iso_code":"AUS","city_name":"brisbane","country_id":"1"},{"id":"5","country_name":"Bangladesh","country_code":"880","iso_code":"BGD","city_name":"dhaka","country_id":"2"},{"id":"6","country_name":"Bangladesh","country_code":"880","iso_code":"BGD","city_name":"chittagong","country_id":"2"}]
```

So for getting required json format what all changes should I make in the model function, I am new to this, Thanking in advance.

Comment: group by dr_country.country_name,dr_city.city_name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this in your model

```
$countries = $this->db->get('dr_country')->result();
foreach ($countries as $key => $country) {
    $country->city = $this->db->get_where('dr_city', array('country_id' => $country->id))->result();
}
print_r(json_encode($countries));
```

Comment: print_r(json_encode($country)); I get only one city (same sydeny)for all countries

Comment: [{"id":"1","country_name":"Australia","country_code":"61","iso_code":"AUS","city":[{"city_id":"1","city_name":"sydney","country_id":"1"}]},{"id":"2","country_name":"Bangladesh","country_code":"880","iso_code":"BGD","city":[{"city_id":"1","city_name":"sydney","country_id":"1"}]}]   this is what I am getting city(sydney) is repeated for all

Answer (score 0):

Please try below steps:

1. Get all the countries - select * from dr_country
2. loop through countries and fetch the cities for each country

   foreach($countries as $c)
   {
     $countries[$city_id]  = select * from dr_city where country_id = $c;
   }

   3. json encode

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output will never come with direct Database.
Because Database gives output in  TABLE formate.

If you want your expected output, than you should execute 2 SQL query.
i) Fetch Country
ii) Fetch City
And Make one foreach loop of Country Array and Find All City related to Country
and Make output Array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $countries = $this->db->get('dr_country')->result();
foreach ($countries as $key => $country) {
    $country->city = $this->db->get_where('dr_city', array('country_id' => 
$country->id))->result();
    $countryfinal[]=$country;
}
print_r(json_encode($countryfinal));
```